Query PHP a SAP HANA con * muestra todo por columna no muestra nada?
Estoy realizando una consulta a SAP HANA desde PHP, la conexión es con ODBC y el problema surge al realizar un select filtrando por columnas especificas ej:

Funciona correcto y muestra todos los datos: SELECT * FROM TABLE;
No muestra ningún dato: SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE;

Me parece extraño que con el comodín de campos funciona correctamente, y con campos específicos deja de funcionar.
Nota: No muestra error alguno solamente no imprime ningún resultado.
Esta es mi clase de conexión a HANA:
   public function ejecutarConsulta($consulta)
    {
        try {
            $conn = odbc_connect($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);

            if (!$conn) {
                throw new \Exception('Error al conectar a la base de datos ODBC');
            }

            $resultado = odbc_exec($conn, $consulta);

            if (!$resultado) {
                throw new \Exception('Error al ejecutar la consulta ODBC');
            }

            $datos = [];
            while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                $datos[] = $row;
            }

            odbc_free_result($resultado);
            odbc_close($conn);

            return $datos;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error en la conexión ODBC: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }


Hola Leo, por lo poco que se puede ver en el código, en caso de que algo falle no vas a ver ningún error, simplemente vas a obtener false como resultado.

¿En lo que sería col1, col2, col3 hay palabras reservadas o caracteres acentuados o ñ o cosas raras? Un ejemplo mínimo y verificable significa que pongas el código real que falla, porque el fallo puede ser debido a acentos, o a que tienes nombres de columnas que son palabras reservadas, en cuyo caso, cuando las escribes explícitamente en la consulta SQL debes usar las comillas identificadoras (backticks). Por otra parte, estás escribiendo en el log de errores, ¿qué lees en él?

A tu pregunta le falta: El mensaje de error que se genera con la llamada a odbc_exec($conn, $consulta);, y también ver cómo construyes esa consulta, es decir, la llamada a ejecutarConsulta($consulta). Sin esas piezas, dudo que alguien pueda decir que es lo que pasa o como resolverlo.

Gracias a los que participaron con sus comentarios, ya lo resolví es un error bastante tonto, resulta que en HANA los nombres de las columnas van entre comillas "col1", "col2". Al agregar comillas a los nombres de las columnas funciono, como nota adicional si usas joins también el nombre de la columna debe ir entre comillas de lo contrario no funciona ej: ON t0."col1" = t1."col1".
